# Is it possible to use a self-generated key for Microsoft EFS encryption?

Tags: encryption

Since the EFS use public key encryption for the FEK, I just wonder if I can use openSSL to generate a self-signed key and then use it as the encryption key instead of using the key generated by Windows ?

Comment: Even if I don't see any reason for doing so that should be possible. But you don't just need a key but also a certificate containing the appropriate fields. The easiest way would be to generate an EFS certificate by Windows, export it and then generate a similar key+certificate and then import it into your personal Windows certificate store.